# GWT: How can I reinitialize a widget in UI binder discarding all changes obtained during its life cycle?

Tags: java, gwt, widget, uibinder

I have a UI-binder-driven composite that consists of a lot of widgets and it is used to render item-specific information. Let's say, it's just a composite like this:

```xml
...

<g:FlowPanel ui:field="itemPanel">
    <g:Label ui:field="title"/>
    <g:Label ui:field="description"/>
    <w:CustomPanel>
        <w:CustomFoo ui:field="foo">
            ...
        </w:CustomFoo>
        <w:CustomBar ui:field="bar">
            ...
        </w:CustomBar>
    </w:CustomPanel>
</g:FlowPanel>

<g:FlowPanel ui:field="itemPanel2">
    ...
</g:FlowPanel>

...
```

At some point I need to hide the first panel, using the the `hide()` method. However, the `hide()` method can be not enough if there's intention to *recreate* (or reinitialize) the `itemPanel` panel, and probably free DOM resources that might be allocated for the `CustomFoo` and `CustomBar` components. Please note that `itemPanel.clear();` destroys all nested widgets, so a consecutive call like `title.setText(...)` has no any effect because the DOM is destroyed in this scenario.

How can I recreate the `itemPanel` as if it has just been loaded from its UI binder again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to clear the changes made in any widget?

Comment: @Braj I'd better say reset the `itemPanel` state, not to clear the panel per se.

Comment: Can you tell me what changes have you done to make it more clear to me?

Comment: @Braj for instance, `title=getTitle()`, `description=getDescription()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make ItemPanel a widget. Then you can use:

```
myCompositeWidget.remove(panel1);
ItemPanel panel2 = new ItemPanel();
myCompositeWidget.add(panel2);
```

You can use insert() instead of add(), if you need a specific position.

Comment: Thank you for an interesting solution. But would it be possible not to maintain the panels in the suggested way? I mean, I think it's an overkill to extract such a panel into another composite and manually recreate it using widget structure manipulation with `add()` and `remove()`.

Comment: You can easily .remove() any widget from your composite, but you cannot add a new one without initializing it first. An alternative solution is to reuse the panel, but then you need to reset its state - something you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. Actually I wanted to use something like `itemPanel.init()` or something like that.